# I'm running a WAMP server. But can't forward ip through router

Tags: networking, server, routes, ip, port

I want to forward the ip of my localhost server for being publicly accessible.
But while trying to configure my router on port 80(as it is localhost's listening port) it shows "Error: The port of the remote web management is conflicting with of the virtual server."
Is there any fix to it?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by updating the Web Management Port to a port other than 80. This setting for me was found under Security -> Remote Management -> Web Management Port.

After updating, I could enable port forwarding on port 80.